# Perfect square and divisibility condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x,y,z$ are integers such that $x^2+y^2=z^2$, prove that one of $x,y$ is divisible by 3
I tried conversely by expressing $x=3*q+r $ but I could not arrive at the proof

Comment: Squares can only be congruent to $0$ or $1$ mod $3$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**: Every number leaves a remainder of $0, 1, 2$ when divided by $3$. If you square the remainders mod $3$, what do you get?